# Reset net-snmp? I've forgotten the initial user password

Tags: solaris, snmp

I created an SNMP initial user several years ago for a project and have forgotten the password. Is there a way to reset net-snmp back to default, no users, and recreate the initial user and subsequent users?
This is on Solaris 10 and Solaris 11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration file that is maintained by `net-snmp` itself. On Debian Linux, it's at `/var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf`; I don't know exactly where net-snmp puts it on Solaris. But that file contains user definitions as long lines, starting with the `usmUser` keyword. The user's password will be stored in encrypted/hashed form, so you cannot read it. But the username will be plainly readable on the line.

You should not edit the file while `snmpd` is running, as `snmpd` will then simply overwrite your changes. But when `snmpd` is stopped, you can edit the file to add a `createUser` line into it to create a new user - when `snmpd` is restarted, it will read the file, detect any `createUser` lines, encrypt the plain-text passwords on those lines, and then replace those `createUser` lines with corresponding `usmUser` lines. That way, you could add a new user with a known password and full admin access without knowing the old password, as long as you have write access to that file and can stop `snmpd` temporarily.

Also, if you remove a user's `usmUser` line (while `snmpd` is stopped), then as far as `snmpd` is concerned, that user no longer exists. So that's one way to delete net-snmp users without knowing the net-snmp admin password.